# No persistence provider for Entity Manager with Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I'm trying to to develop a simple rest API project with Java and Tomcat. The HTTP request works correctly, but I'm figuring out a lot of problem by implementing a database MySQL to store data. This is my persistence.xml file, that is located in Java Resources/META-INF:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="PERSISTENCE">
    <description> Hibernate JPA Configuration Example</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.resourceserver.Person</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/RESTResourceServer" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is my PersonDAO.java and JPAUtil.java class:

```
public class PersonDao {

    EntityManager entityManager;

    public PersonDao() {
        entityManager = JPAUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    public void storePerson(Person person) {
        entityManager.persist(person);
        // people.add(person);
    }

    public void deletePerson(Person person) {
        entityManager.remove(person);
        // people.remove(person);
    }

    public Person findPersonId(int id) {
        /*
         * for (Person person : people) { if (person.getId() == id) { return person; } }
         */
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> getAllUsers() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("Select p From People p ");
        return query.getResultList();
        // return people;
    }
}

public class JPAUtil {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "PERSISTENCE";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        }
        return factory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if (factory != null) {
            factory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And in my Endpoint I simple use PersonDao persona = new PersonDao() to perform the operations; where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the persistence provider (no surprise there!)

Most likely you have added the JPA API as a dependency but forgot to add a concrete implementation like Hibernate or EclipseLink. This means you can compile the whole thing because the interfaces for JPA are there but there are not implementing classes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where should I provide this information? In the POM?

Comment: Yes. You have to add the hibernate dependency to the hibernate-entitymanager to the dependency section. <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I've already that line of code and also after an Update of the maven, I've the same problem...

Comment: Is it included in the war?

Comment: I'm running it using eclipse.. Do you mean should I verify if there is the jar in the lib?

Comment: Since few years all my Tomcat installations are migrated to Tomee. Have JPA too (OpenJPA by default). Perfectly compatible with 'classic' Tomcat, and nothing bad happens.

Comment: Getting things running under Eclipse should be step 2. Getting it to run with a Tomcat started from the command line is first.